# STEM Graduate School Accepted/Denied

Tags: discussion

I was hoping we could start a [gradcafe](http://thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=computer%20science%20&t=a&o=) style post for STEM Graduate Applications including:

School (or Description):
GRE: Q/V/W
GPA:
Major GPA:
Accepted/Denied:
Extracurriculars/Research:

Answer (score 12):

I disagree with this because it isn't a question. This site is for questions and answers. Let's leave things like this for forums.

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with this, because you'd need separate posts for each discipline, and the answers won't "curate" well—what suffices for acceptance one year may result in denial the next.